# blocking facebooks news feed page but not other pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, blocking

I am using website blocker to block facebook.com
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/website-blocker-beta/hclgegipaehbigmbhdpfapmjadbaldib?hl=en

I dont want to see facebook.com but still want to access facebook.com/messages
or facebook.com/someCommunity

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome Nanny](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nanny-for-google-chrome-t/cljcgchbnolheggdgaeclffeagnnmhno) is a Chrome extension that also allows whitelisting, thus you can block `facebook.com` and whitelist `facebook.com/messages` and `facebook.com/someCommunity`, and you will only be able to use those pages (as well as things like `facebook.com/messages/myfriendsname`, so you can still chat). Unfortunately the settings for this extension can be a little more confusing, but it allows for much more functionality.